# Problem playing sound with pulseaudio virtual sound device inside kubernetes container

Tags: dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, alsa, google-cloud-speech, pulseaudio

I'm trying to deploy to kubernetes (GKE) my Fastapi application of 'speech to speech Translation' by creating a container using 'Cloud Build' inside Google Cloud (GCP). I've created an *entrypoint.sh file* to configure pulseaudio that created pulseaudio virtual sink, set default source and sink as the virtual device, start pulseaudio and also start my application using uvicorn, code as shown below:

```
#Entrypoint.sh to configure PulseAudio
#!/bin/bash
# Set environment variables
export PULSE_IGNORE_ALSA=1
# set environment variable to disable ALSA
export PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1
export PYAUDIO_BACKEND=pulse
export PULSE_SINK=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink
export PULSE_SOURCE=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink

sudo chown root:audio /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/client.conf #/etc/asound.conf
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/client.conf #/etc/asound.conf

sudo pactl set-default-setting autospawn no -k

# Setting the default pcm and ctl to use virtualsink that will be created in the next lines
#sudo pactl load-config -k <<EOF
#pcm.pulse {
#  type pulse
#}
#ctl.pulse {
#  type pulse
#}
#pcm.!default {
#  type pulse
#  playback.pcm "FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink"
#  capture.pcm "FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink"
#}
#ctl.!default {
#  type pulse
#}
#EOF

# Craeting Pulse Audio virtual sink and setting it as default source and sink for ALSA use
sudo pactl load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink sink_properties=device.description=Virtual_Sink -k
sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink sink_name=VirtualSink -k
sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink source_name=VirtualSource -k
sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-sink control=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink -k
sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-source control=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink -k

sudo pactl set-default-sink VirtualSink -k
sudo pactl set-default-source VirtualSource -k
sudo pactl default-server=tcp:0.0.0.0 -k
sudo pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-anonymous=1 listen=8000 auth-ip-acl=0.0.0.0 -k
sudo pactl set-allow-access group:audio

# Configure the PulseAudio daemon for all 
echo 'server:
      sinks:
        - name: "FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink"
          type: pulse' | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/default.pa > /dev/null #>> /etc/pulse/default.pa


# Start PulseAudio
#sudo pulseaudio --kill
sudo pulseaudio --daemon --system --log-level=debug --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading -k

# Change directory to /app ans starting the uvicorn
cd /app
sleep 10 # Delay for PulseAudio to fully start
uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --env-file /app/virtualsinkenv.txt
```

My *Dockerfile* that builbs a Docker Image looks like below:

```
# Dockerfile to built Docker Image

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Declaring necessary environment variables and Path
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib:${PATH}"

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

# set environment variable to disable ALSA
ENV PULSE_IGNORE_ALSA=1
ENV PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1
ENV PYAUDIO_BACKEND=pulse
ENV PULSE_SINK=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink
ENV PULSE_SOURCE=FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink

# Set the environment variable for the Streamlit command
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    #PATH=$PATH:/app \
    HOST=0.0.0.0 \
    #HOST=127.0.0.1 \
    PORT=8000
    #PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \

# Making a directory /app and setting it as work directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH="/app:$PATH"

# Add the root user to the 'audio' group
RUN adduser root audio

# Create and activate a virtual environment
RUN python -m venv /app/venv
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"
#RUN echo "source /app/venv/bin/activate" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate
ENV PATH="/app/venv:$PATH"
ENV PATH=$PATH:/bin

# Installing build essentials and necessary libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc --no-install-recommends build-essential apt-utils sudo && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends pulseaudio \
        #python-gnuradio-audio-portaudio alsa-base #alsa is the default audio driver in Ubuntu, pulseaudio is a higher level audio driver
        portaudio19-dev libasound2-dev libportaudio2 libasound2-plugins libportaudiocpp0 libsndfile1-dev \
        #python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio \
        libpulse0 pulseaudio-utils  libpulse-dev \
        ffmpeg \
        #alsa-utils winealsa pyalsaaudio build-essential\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set file permissions
RUN chown root:audio /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/client.conf
RUN chmod 755 /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/client.conf

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY media_translation_api_key.json /app/media_translation_api_key.json
#COPY alsa-config-pulse.yaml /app/venv/alsa-config-pulse.yaml
# Copy the script containg speech-to-speech code with 
COPY mediatrans_blob_FastAPI.py /app/mediatrans_blob_FastAPI.py
COPY main.py /app/main.py
COPY virtualsinkenv.txt /app/virtualsinkenv.txt

ENV PATH="/etc:$PATH"
ENV PATH="/etc/pulse:$PATH"
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/pulseaudio:$PATH"

# Setting additional ownership/permission just for safer side
RUN chown -R root:audio /app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app
RUN chown -R root:audio /etc
RUN chmod -R 755 /etc
RUN chown -R root:audio /app/venv
RUN chmod -R 755 /app/venv
RUN chown -R root:audio /etc/pulse
RUN chmod -R 755 /etc/pulse

###########......Install pip within the virtual environment
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /app/requirements.txt --upgrade pip

# Install Google SDK and GCP dependencies
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
# Set file permissions for entrypoint script
RUN chown root:audio /app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /app/entrypoint.sh

# Expose the port on which the app will run
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

However, when I try to deploy this to Google Kubernetes Engine I can see the FastAPI app opening and taking source and target language inputs but no sound is getting played. When I inspected K8 Logs I see the below error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure whey i'm seeing ALSA related error when I defined default-ALSA source and sink to use my crated virtual device which is in entrypoint code as '*FastAPI_virtual_audio_sink*'. Also I'm clueless whey I see error 'you have to specify a source and sink name' when I had mentioned that in entrypoint.sh

Looking for an expert opinion. Please suggest what is going wrong and what to change in the code above.